# deploying nodeJS aps on Azure via Docker-compose

Tags: node.js, azure, docker, docker-compose

General deployment type question. I have a series of docker containers orchestrated via docker compose. Most of these services are written in NodeJS. So the thing is that I have thoroughly tested the integration of my app end-to-end on various OSX and linux(ubuntu xenial) machines but when I try to follow the same deployment pattern on an Azure VM I start getting

```
segmentation faults (core dumped) exit code 139
```

from some of my nodejs apps, specially when I run `npm install`.

The only thing I have been installing on the VMs is docker and docker-compose - both latest stable releases.

For reference, I tried the worko around that's specified here https://github.com/kelektiv/node.bcrypt.js/issues/528 but that did not work.

So I was wondering if there is anyone here who has come across similar problems?

Comment: Use `npm rebuild` to recompile your dependencies. Then retry.